# PHP XML parsing with values using encoding=base64

Tags: php, xml, encoding, base64

How does one parse XML that contains values that are encoded. In my case I have a number of values that are encoded with base64:

```
<value encoding="base64">...</value>
```

Using SimpleXML it appears to ignore the encoding. So there must be a different way...

Comment: Why not just `base64_decode` these strings to get the values you need?

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve the values and then decode them using PHP function:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

so the XML lib will get the content for you but you'll have to then do what you need with the content to make use of it.

Comment: Yea, I know about base64-decoding. But I thought that encoding attribute was a standard mechanism for XML, but perhaps I am wrong...

Comment: you can have any attribute within XML (X = eXtensible) and unless you have a strict XSD or DTD that defines the rules of the document, or XSL stylesheet to define transformation, it's really just a smart wrapper for any kind of content.  Think of XML more as a container with a label on it and you can place anything inside, but hopefully it has something to do with the label so useful for others.  You still have to parse the XML to retrieve the contents, then do what you wish with contents.