# How to add pdf document as code in xml file (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, pdf, invoice

I am creating pdf and xml files for invoices separately.

But now as per new rule I need to send **pdf doc in the xml file** as code (base64Binary [RFC 2045]).

**In PHP**, I am using **SimpleXMLElement()** function.

Should I use encoded pdf in xml as taxt in a tag(attachment)?

Comment: I think that the down vote is because you said that you searched a lot on this but nothing found. There are plenty of tuts on how to do that!

Comment: Ok Fine, I will remember this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that

```
$xmlString = <<<XML 
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document> 
    <cmd>login</cmd> 
    <login>Richard</login> 
</document> 
XML; 
$base64Pdf = base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.pdf'));
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$simpleXml->addChild('document', $base64Pdf);
```

Code to decode pdf.

```
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$encodedPdf = $simpleXml->document;
$decodedPdf = base64_decode($encodedPdf);
file_put_contents("/path/to/decoded.pdf", $decodedPdf);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. :)

Comment: elefher, I try same but encoded text is too big and its breaking xml file. I mean no xml file is creating instead just showing simple text.

Comment: Try to put the encoded pdf in CDATA. For example, <![CDATA[encoded_pdf]]> and put this as a child in your XML

Comment: how to use CDATA for $Allegati->addChild('Attachment', $varPdfBase64);

Comment: $varPdfBase64 = "<![CDATA[" .  $varPdfBase64 . "]]>";

Comment: Please check my question here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499656/php-xml-parsing-with-values-using-encoding-base64

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the contents of the document and transform into base64 and put in your XML tag

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

something close to it.

```
$file = "file.pdf";


$content = file_get_contents($file);

$base64 = base64_encode($content);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$xml->addChild('file', "$base64");

print $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am also on the same solution :)

Comment: Sure, I will but please let me check for more answers.

Comment: I try same but encoded text is too big and its breaking xml file. I mean no xml file is creating instead just showing simple text.